# EmberJs - Route all the actions coming from sub-component into the parent component, to the parent controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Is there is way to route ALL the actions hitting from a component to the parent controller?

The source of these actions hitting the component is from the sub-components it contains.

Problem here is that ***i do not readily know from the name of the action*** coming into the component, but they will be defined in the parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the details of your scenario, it's difficult to help, a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com) might clear things up.

Just make sure you have the following section of the guides down, 
[calling-actions-up-multiple-component-layers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/#toc_calling-actions-up-multiple-component-layers).

What I can recommend without knowing much else, is that if your struggling with handling actions in multiple components, inject a service into the relevant components and handle the state and actions in the service.

Comment: The question as it stands should be closed as off topic for missing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this answer should be a comment.